# What should i write in parameter of a method in android

Tags: android, android-activity, this, oncreate

i am making an android application in which i want to pass "this" object of onCreate method in another method. What should i write in the parameter to catch that object correctly. Because i want to add objects into view.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary);
    showhistory(this);

    //other code
}

void showhistory(what should i write here??)
{
    TextView historyword[] = new TextView[rs.getColumnCount()];
    for(int i=0;i<rs.getColumnCout();i++)
        historyword[i] = new TextView(i want **this** object of onCreate method here);
}
```

please help. Thank you.

Comment: Since `showhistory()` is an instance method in the same class, you don't need a method parameter; you can just use `this` inside the method, just as you do inside `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using your method in any activity or service, then no need to pass context,because they have their own context. Just use `this` (context) wherever you need.
so your code will look like:

```
void showhistory()
{
    TextView historyword[] = new TextView[rs.getColumnCount()];
    for(int i=0;i<rs.getColumnCout();i++)
        historyword[i] = new TextView(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Context` as context is needed for the creation of `TextView`

```
void showhistory(Context context)
{
    TextView historyword[] = new TextView[rs.getColumnCount()];
    for(int i=0;i<rs.getColumnCout();i++)
        historyword[i] = new TextView(context);
}
```